prove by induction that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+\frac{1}{2^i} \right)} <2.5$
Prove using mathematical induction:
$$P(n) = \left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^2}\right)\ldots\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^n}\right) < \frac{5}{2} \tag{1}
$$
Hint: By mathematical induction, it is difficult to derive $P(n+1) < \frac{5}{2}$ from $P(n) < \frac{5}{2}$. If we can find a positive term sequence $a_n$ that satisfies:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right) < \frac{5}{2} - a_n \tag{2}
$$
Then (1) is proven, meaning that if (2) holds, then (1) follows.
Some additional information:

It can be proven that (1) is less than e:
\begin{aligned}
&\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right) \\
&= \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)} \\
&= e^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)} \\
&< e^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}} \\
&= e
\end{aligned}
In mathematics, the definition of the Euler function is:
$$\phi(q) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-q^k\right), \quad |q| < 1.$$
Named after Leonhard Euler, it is a model example of a q-series and provides a prototype example of the relationship between combinatorics and complex analysis.Noting that $P(n)$ is monotonically increasing, let $x = \frac{1}{2}$,
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty}P(n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right) \\
&= \prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n) \\
&= \prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-x^{2n})}{(1-x^n)} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{2n})}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)} \\
&= \frac{\phi\left(x^2\right)}{\phi\left(x\right)} \\
&= \frac{\phi\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\phi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \approx 2.38423
\end{aligned}
Here, an approximate result is given, for more details refer to Wikipedia.
A similar problem:
$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right) = 2$$
Can be proven using the difference of squares formula:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{n+1}}} = 1
$$

here are some method to prove it without using induction（not what I want）

when $x>0,1+x<e^x$
\begin{align}
&\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right)}
&\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right)}
&\\
&<\frac{3}{2}\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}
&\\
&=\frac{3}{2}e^{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^n}}}
&\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{e}
&\\
&\approx 2.47308
&
\end{align}
let $g\left( n \right) =\frac{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right)}{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right)}>0$ and is monotonically decreasing
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right)}{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right)}=g\left( n \right) <g\left( 1 \right) =\frac{\ln \frac{5}{4}}{\ln \frac{3}{2}}
&\\
&\mathrm{when}\quad n>2
&\\
&\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) \le \frac{\ln \frac{5}{4}}{\ln \frac{3}{2}}\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right) \le \left( \frac{\ln \frac{5}{4}}{\ln \frac{3}{2}} \right) ^2\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right) \le \left( \frac{\ln \frac{5}{4}}{\ln \frac{3}{2}} \right) ^n\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2} \right) 
&\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right)}
&\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\ln \frac{3}{2}}\left( \frac{\ln \frac{5}{4}}{\ln \frac{3}{2}} \right) ^n
&\\
&=\frac{\ln \frac{3}{2}}{1-\frac{\ln \frac{5}{4}}{\ln \frac{3}{2}}}
&\\
&\approx 0.901714
&\\
&<\ln \frac{5}{2}\approx 0.91
&
\end{align*}

Reference：
Determine convergence of the sequence $x_0=1 , x_{n+1}=x_n (1+ 2^{-(n+1)})$

The hint of (2) is good. What have you tried in that regard? what form of $a_n$ could work?

@CalvinLin，$a_n$should tend to 0,I have tried some,but they does not work

@AnneBauval,why?I have proved it is less than $\mathrm{e}$

@AnneBauval, thanks for your  reminding

For the induction to work, we want

$ (\frac{ 5}{2} - a_n ) ( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) <  (\frac{ 5}{2} - a_{n+1} ) \Rightarrow \frac{5}{2^{n+2}} + a_{n+1} < a_n( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}})   $
$ a_{n} \rightarrow 0$
A suitable starting index.

It is not necessary that we start with $n=1$.
We want the initial value to satisfy $a_1 < 1$,  $a_2 <5/8$, $a_3 < 25/64$ etc.



Based on this, we can guess several possible forms for $a_i$, and test against the conditions above. Can you take it from here?
It would be great if you can find a form of $a_n$ that starts with $n=1$. (To be clear, I don't know if this is definitely possible.)
The form I used:

 Condition 1: To easily satisfy the inequality, I chose $\frac{5}{2^{n+2}} + a_{n+1} = a_n$, so $ a_n = \frac{5}{2^{n+1}}$.
 Condition 2: This is clearly satisfied.
 Condition 3: Starting value of $n = 3$ (for strict inequality)


If $0<x<1$ then $\log (1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}$ from the criteria of alternate series. Therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log (1+\frac{1}{2^i})\leq \frac{37}{42}\leq \log \frac{5}{2}.$$
Thanks Gribouillis...

I like short proofs...

Using your additional information $2$ we have
$$P(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\prod_{i\ge n+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)\approx2.38423\implies P(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\approx\frac{2.38423}{\prod_{i\ge n+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)}$$ and
$$P(n+1)=P(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\approx\frac{2.38423}{\prod_{i\ge n+2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)}\lt\frac{2.38423}{1+k}\lt2.38423\lt\frac52$$ where $k\gt0$.
All is given now.

Isn't this argument somewhat circular? It took a lot of machinery to prove that the limit is 2.38, which you're then using to explain why a sub-product of it is less than 2.38.
